# Camel Proxy support in Camel 3

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have an use case where a Spring bean is defined like so:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="my.java.IntfImpl"/>
```

The class my.java.IntfImpl, which implements my.java.Intf, needs to be swapped with a Camel based implementation. For Camel 2.x, I could have done this:

```
<proxy id="camelProxy"
            serviceInterface="my.java.Intf"
            serviceUrl="direct:start"/>
```

And then I rewire my bean like so:

```
<bean id="myBean" parent="camelProxy"/>
```

The problem is that Camel 3.x does not support CamelProxy. So how do I achieve the same with Camel 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to address the issue by using org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate. In the implementation class my.java.IntfImplCamel, I am injecting an instance of ProducerTemplate using Produce annotation. This instance is used to send the payload among with headers to the Camel route.

```
public class IntfImplCamel implements my.java.Intf {
  @Produce("direct:startRoute)
  private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;
  
  @Override
  public String methodImpl() {
       Object retVal = doStuff();
       producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(producerTemplate.getDefaultEndpoint(), retVal, "MyHeader", 
            "MyHeaderValue");
  }
}
```

I am wiring an instance of my.java.IntfImplCamel to myBean like so:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="my.java.IntfImplCamel"/>
```

This enables me to let the consumers of myBean use a Camel route instead of a Java implementation seamlessly, without making code changes in the consumer.