# How to use <proxy> with Camel 4 and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-spring-dsl

Camel-spring 3 used to have a configuration field for XML called `<proxy>` ([see XML schema](https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-3.0.0.xsd))

For example:

```
<proxy id="myAbcService"
    serviceInterface="com.test.MyAbcService"
    serviceUrl="direct:abcService"/>
```

Upgrading to Camel 4, this property is gone in the [spring-camel XML definition](https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd). Commenting this out causes `NoSuchBeanDefinitionExeption`.

What is the alternative to `<proxy>` in Camel 4?

The [upgrade docs](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_9.html) mention this functionality is removed, but doesn't explain any alternative for upgrading.

> In Spring XML <proxy> and <remote> have been removed. They were only available in Spring XML and not in the other XML DSLs (Blueprint and CDI).

Answer (score 0):

maybe this Answer is helping you:

[Manage Proxy with custom Bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67597892/camel-proxy-support-in-camel-3)

Its pointing out, that you can inject an instance of ProducerTemplate in a custom bean to make your request.